Regarding the Channel Impulse Response extraction from the Channel State Information of Wi-Fi working with OFDM Subcarriers and implement it on python
I have extracted the Channel State Information [CSI] matrix from the Intel AX210 card and I have performed an IFFT in python to gain its Channel Impulse Response [CIR]. Since each sub carriers reflects the multi-path delays, scatters and refraction of the signal. Performing IFFT of CSI seems reasonable having to compromise with BW of the system which in my case is 160 MHz.

When I take the IFFts of the CSI matrix i do get and impulse but how can I define the time index ? considering I have 53 Sub carriers in CSI matrix working on 160 MHz bandwidth and the center frequency is 6046 MHz.

What kind of experiments I can perform to validate whether my reading or codes is functioning properly as at 160 MHz the resolution i get is 1.87meters, it means even the LOS would be detected If i keep my transmitter and receiver more than 1.87 meters apart?


Please If anyone have any idea or knowledge or any code which shows the time index and explain it, please share with me
